# casting a pydantic base model attribute to a list

Tags: pydantic

I have a class that inherits from base model, and is defined as below:

```
class MessageInfo(CustomBaseModel):
    completion_code: int = None
    code: str = None
    message: str = None
    severity: str = None
```

```
class OrderResponseMessageInfo(CustomBaseModel):
    message_info: Union[List[MessageInfo], MessageInfo] = None
```

Want this message_info to be able to consume either a list or a dict, but consistently produce it as a list when i serialise it to a dict or a json.

Since this is a parser for an API response, and the API response is not consistent, i.e sometimes the message info block is an array like so :

```
{
    "MessageInfo": [
        {
            "CompletionCode": 517,
            "Code": "1B61",
            "Message": "some message",
            "Severity": "Warning"
        },
        {
            "CompletionCode": 9886,
            "Code": "1B61",
            "Message": "Another message",
            "Severity": "Warning"
        }
    ]
}
```

And sometimes its a dict like so

```
{
    "MessageInfo": {
        "CompletionCode": 517,
        "Code": "1B61",
        "Message": "some message",
        "Severity": "Warning"
    }
}
```

When message info is a dict, and I do OrderResponseMessageInfo.dict(), i get

```
{
    "OrderLineMessageInfo": {
        "MessageInfo": {
                "CompletionCode": 517,
                "Code": "1B61",
                "Message": "Routing completed. Confirmation required.",
                "Severity": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

What i want is that if message info is a dict, then i should be able to type cast it to a list, so that when I do OrderResponseMessageInfo.dict(), i should get the output as:

```
{
    "OrderLineMessageInfo": {
        "MessageInfo": [
            {
                "CompletionCode": 517,
                "Code": "1B61",
                "Message": "Routing completed. Confirmation required.",
                "Severity": "Warning"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you should define your models in terms of the schema you *actually want*, not in terms of what you *might get*.

If you want a field to be of a list type, then define it as such. If you then want to allow singular elements to be turned into one-item-lists as a special case during parsing/initialization, you can define a custom [`pre=True` field validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) to do that.

Either way, at the end of the parsing and validation process you should end up with your **desired** schema, not something you need to mangle *again* at some stage.

Example:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: str


class Bar(BaseModel):
    foos: list[Foo]

    @validator("foos", pre=True)
    def single_to_list(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, (Mapping, Foo)):
            return [Foo.parse_obj(v)]
        return v
```

Demo:

```py
b1 = Bar.parse_raw('{"foos": [{"x": 1, "y": "spam"}, {"x": -1, "y": "eggs"}]}')
b2 = Bar.parse_raw('{"foos": {"x": 42, "y": "ham"}}')
f = Foo(x=69, y="beans")
b3 = Bar.parse_obj({"foos": f})
b4 = Bar.parse_obj({"foos": [f, f]})
print(b1.json(indent=4))
print(b2.json(indent=4))
print(b3.json(indent=4))
print(b4.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "foos": [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": "spam"
        },
        {
            "x": -1,
            "y": "eggs"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "foos": [
        {
            "x": 42,
            "y": "ham"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "foos": [
        {
            "x": 69,
            "y": "beans"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "foos": [
        {
            "x": 69,
            "y": "beans"
        },
        {
            "x": 69,
            "y": "beans"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want `message_info` to be a list, then define it as `list[MessageInfo]` and write a custom validator to try and coerce any mapping or `MessageInfo` instance to a list containing one `MessageInfo` instance.

Of course you *could* instead override the dumping/serialization methods (like `.dict` and `.json`), but I would not recommend it. 1) That would result in more code, 2) it would be less efficient, 3) the model schema would still be misleading because you would *always* dump that field as a list, but the schema would imply a single instance *might* appear.

Comment: I can see how its better to handle such variations while initialising the model, rather than having to handle at the time of serialisation. pre=True did the trick for me. Neat stuff. Thanks much. Really appreciate :)